# Why CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS always returns false?

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know what i am doing wrong here but i have been trying to get this to work for hours. i just want it to create a table that doesn't exist. i made it as simple as i can make it and still it just returns false and doesn't change anything. please let me what i am doing wrong thank you in advance.

```
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db("test",$conn);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'works' (
   `autoPlace` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `element` float(255) NOT NULL,
   `month` tinyint(4) NOT NULL ,
   `mday`   tinyint(4) NOT NULL ,
   `wday` char(12) NOT NULL ,
   `time` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`autoPlace`)     
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

$thisKeepsReturningFalse= mysql_query($sql);
  var_dump($thisKeepsReturningFalse);

Comment: You should use PDO rather than the deprecated `mysql_` functions on all new development anyway.

Comment: Use backticks around `works` and not quotes.

Answer (score 4):

When I tried to execute your query I got this error:

```
Incorrect column specifier for column 'element'
```

The problem is `float(255)` is not a valid declaration

It needs to be `float(x)` where `x<=53`, or you can use `float(x,y)`  - see [mysql docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html)

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you have single quotes around `works`. Remove them or replace them with backticks.

After fixing these errors, I was able to successfully execute your query.

Comment: "A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column.". I don't think you need to give two values, it just needs to be 0-53. But better to leave off the precision altogether; just choose `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` unless what you really need is a `DECIMAL`.

Comment: I was going to vote up your comment @Mark but strangely enough, it seems like I've reached my daily upvote limit. Oh well, +1 ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Lol no worries it's the thought that counts :)

Comment: @MarkM: Well, this is awkward.

Comment: Well, the OP's in good hands here (with both Mark's). No sense for me to place an answer. ;-) will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

"CREATE" command in MySQL is not return value command so that it always return false(not like SELECT). To check if the command "CREATE" success or not, you can use "SHOW TABLES" to check after executing the "CREATE" command.

Comment: thank you good to know but i guess i worded the question poorly its not creating the table either

Comment: @Phuc: that's not true: "For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error." (see [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a float element you must specify the decimals with a comma.And also the name of the table can't be with this format '' it must to be inside ``.

So in this example the query should be :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `works` 
(
    `autoPlace` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `element` float(255,0) NOT NULL,
    `month` tinyint(4) NOT NULL ,
    `mday`   tinyint(4) NOT NULL ,
    `wday` char(12) NOT NULL ,
    `time` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`autoPlace`)     
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Note how the float it's float(255,0) and not just 255. You must set this , 0 is the default